# How do you omit N/A data from a given set of values?

Tags: r, na, omittag

A dataframe that is not tidy is given, some values have usable data, others are blank and non-applicable. If possible, could this be done in loop form.

I have tried omit.NA(dataframe), this does not work or it does not remove all characters.

Comment: Can you provide an example data.frame and show the expected output?

Comment: When providing an example, please also make clear what your expected result is. Do you want to remove entire rows or entire cols that contain one NA? If not, you might actually be looking for *imputation*.